# If $p^n \mid |G|$ then the finite p-group $G$ has a normal subgroup of order $p^n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Suppose that $G$ is a finite p-group. Show that if $p^n \mid |G|$ then $G$ has a normal subgroup of order $p^n$.

I am stuck on this problem. I know that $G$ has subgroups of order $p^m$ but I don't know how to find a normal subgroup. Any hints?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** Proceed by induction on $n$. Start with the fact that a $p$ group has nontrivial center, and any quotient of a $p$ group is a $p$ group.